# How to query and map data from another table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have DynamoDB tables orders, products and user.

In orders I have `prouctid` and `user_email`.

I want to get every product detail from orders table using `productid`.

```
async function getUserOrders(id) {
  let params = {
    TableName: table_name_orders,
    IndexName: "UserEmail",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#email = :v_email",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#email": "user_email",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_email": id,
    },
  };

  let allData = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();

  return buildResponse(200, allData.Items);
}
```

In this I am querying all orders for a specific user this orders has product id which is pointing to product I want to get every product data of every order how do I get those.

Is there any function like populate(Mongodb) which populate every item in array with the data?

Comment: have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yqfmXiZTlM for some ideas how you could adjust your data model to get the data easier and faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamoDB batchGetItem API - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Example in java:-

// product table hashKeys list

List idList;

// Using Java SDK for BatchGet

Map<String, TableName.class> claim = dynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(Collections.singletonMap(TableName.class, idList.stream().distinct() .map(i -> new KeyPair().withHashKey(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()))).get("").stream() .map(object -> (TableName class) object).collect(Collectors.toMap(Claim::getClaimId, Function.identity(), (i1, i2) -> i2));

Comment: can you give me a snippet of nodejs code ?

i am stuck on this problem right now what i am doing is looping for every query getting data from products table for every orderId